# Sklearn stop on loss plateau during manual training

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, loss-function

Working with `sklearn`, the `fit` function of `MLPClassifier` is a nice one-size-fits-all solution; you call it once, and it trains until it hits the maximum number of iterations, or the training loss plateaus, all without any interaction. However, I had to change my code to accommodate some other features, and the standard `fit` function isn't configurable enough for what I want to do. I reconfigured my code to use `partial_fit` instead, manually running each iteration one at a time; but I can't figure out how to get my code to recognize when the loss plateaus, like in the `fit` function. I can't seem to find any properties or methods of `MLPClassifier` that allow me to access the loss value calculated by `partial_fit`, so that I can judge if the loss has plateau'd. It seems to me the only way to judge loss across each iteration would be to calculate it myself, despite the fact that `partial_fit` already calculates it, and even prints it to the console in verbose mode.

Edit: Running `partial_fit` manually still does cause the training algorithm to recognize when training loss stops improving; it prints the message `Training loss did not improve more than tol=0.000100 for 10 consecutive epochs. Stopping.` after each iteration, once the training loss plateaus. However, because i'm controlling the iterations manually, it doesn't actually stop, and I have no way of figuring out in my code whether or not this message has been printed in order to stop it manually.

Comment: Could you please be more specific why you think that you would need to interact with your model during the training process?

Comment: I'd like to be able to stop it early if the loss plateaus sooner than the max iteration count.

Comment: Also, it continuously prints out the `Training loss did not improve...` message every iteration once it recognizes that a plateau has been reached, despite not actually stopping. I'd want it to actually stop when it hits that point, if possible.

Comment: If I could just get access to the training loss value that `partial_fit` prints out in verbose mode, that would be sufficient. But I can't seem to access even that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to manually log the loss in a list:

```
loss_list = list()
clf =  MLPClassifier()
#partial fit and so on
print(clf.loss_)
loss_list.append(clf.loss_)
```

I can provide you with a stopping criterion if this code is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed; as long as I have access to the loss value, I can continue. I'll test this out and make sure it's what I need.

Comment: On a side note: I would recommend to use keras for working with neural networks if you need more complex methods. :)

Comment: Finally, is there any way to suppress that `Training loss did not improve...` message from being written?

Comment: Actually, just found out that I can just set `_no_improvement_count = 0` at the start of every iteration, and the message should never get printed.